# I have data table in my page and data table sort is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have data table in my page and I want to add sort in my table but its is not working.

View:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/custom/css/custom_style.css">

<style>
   .highlight { background-color: #1DA5FF; color:#fff; }
    th,
    td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        direction: rtl;
    }

    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Vazir;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    th {
        min-width: 80px;
        height: 32px;
        border: 1px solid #222;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    td {

        min-width: 80px;
        height: 32px;
        border: 1px solid #222;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  td{
    padding: 0;
  }  
  </style>

<form role="form" id="print_booking_register" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <section class="content">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="booking_register_table" class="table table-bordered  table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;"> </table>
         </div>
     </div>
  </section>
</form>
 <button id="print" name="print"  onclick="printContent('print_booking_register')" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary fa fa-newspaper-o col-10 offset-1" style="margin-top: 35px; margin-bottom: 25px;" data-clicked="unclicked"> Print Booking Register</button>


<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script href=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src=" <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>


<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#booking_register_table').dataTable({
       order: [[ 3, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]]
      });

    });
 </script>

<script>
     function printContent(e1) {
     event.preventDefault();

          var allVals = [];

        $('input[name=selectedrecord]:not(:checked').each(function() {
           allVals.push($(this).val());
           });

                  allVals.forEach(function(i){
            $('tr').each(function(){
            $(this).find('td, th').eq(i-1).css({

                       display:'none'

                 });
        });
      });

      $('#print').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //hiding print button on print page
      $('input[name=selectedrecord]').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //hiding Check box on print page

      var restorepage     = document.innterHTML;
      var printContent    = document.getElementById(e1).innterHTML;
      document.innterHTML = printContent;
      window.print();
      document.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"; 
      location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/report/booking_register/BookingRegisterController/bookingRegister", 'refresh';
       }

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Controller:

```
$modelResult = $this->reportModel->bookingRegisterReportByLrno($data);
?>
  <table id="bilty_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;">
            <thead>
             <tr>
              <th class="col2"><input   type="checkbox" name="selectedrecord" value="2">LR No</th>
              <th class="col3"><input   type="checkbox" name="selectedrecord" value="3">Consignor Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <?php foreach($modelResult as $bilty){?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $counter;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $bilty->lr_no;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $bilty->consignor;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Added jquery file in my code but i this it not support.
I do not know that where I am wrong in my code. 
I try this code but its not working.
I have table in my controller  and I am showing in view page

Comment: Don't post controller code, since this is a client-side problem. Post a [mre] of client side code (using the final HTML!). You should also check your `<script>` tags; you're including stuff twice. Also, are you getting error messages in the browser console?

Comment: @ChrisG it give error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`

Comment: Ok, so we're back at you creating a [mre].

Comment: @Chris G that's not my answer